# My android app uses WebView which sometime prompts for location is it necessary to add <uses-feature> in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

In manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I use WebView in my android app to display some websites which **may** request location. 4 out of 100 websites request location sometimes. So that means that if location is not provided then application will also work, it will load other 96 websites. So is there any need to add following tag in manifest since I am using location permission?

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="true" />
```

I am asking this question because there is one note on documentation page which says:

**Caution: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher and uses the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to receive location updates from the network or a GPS, respectively, you must also explicitly declare that your app uses the android.hardware.location.network or android.hardware.location.gps hardware features.**

Note that I am targeting api level 30 so I am using **android.hardware.location**

**Now my question:**
Since 96 websites will work in WebView without location can I set android:required="false" in  tag?

Comment: This depends on your requirement. **True** - _you are specifying that the application cannot function, or is not designed to function, when the specified feature is not present on the device._ And **False** - _it means that the application prefers to use the feature if present on the device, but that it is designed to function without the specified feature, if necessary._ If you are okay with displaying 96 websites, then it can be false BUT if you need to display all 100 websites, then it should be set to True

Comment: So if I set required="false" in <uses-feature> then app will be available to all users? And 100 websites will work correctly if there are location HW components available otherwise 96 websites will work correctly (I mean they will function as intended). Am I correct?

Comment: In short, Yes. _If a feature is explicitly declared as not being required, Google Play does not add the feature to the list of required features. For that reason, an explicitly declared non-required feature is never considered when filtering the application. Even if the device does not provide the declared feature, Google Play will still consider the application compatible with the device and will show it to the user, unless other filtering rules apply._ Do also note that **The default value for android:required if not declared is "true".**

Comment: 100 Websites will only display if the device has the corresponding feature AND  if you are **granted** access to it. If you set the feature required to **False** and the device DOES NOT have the feature, you'll not be able to display all 100 websites.

Comment: Thanks for your help so that means that I can display 96 websites confirmly even if required="false" and feature is not available? Just one more question since I am using target api level 30 I will require android.hardware.location or android.hardware.location.gps?

Comment: First question - yes. Once again, if required = false, the app will **not be** filtered on PlayStore for devices that **do not** have the corresponding feature. Second question - depends on what you need. Location - _The app uses one or more features on the device for determining location, such as GPS location, network location, or cell location._ **AND** location.gps - _The app uses precise location coordinates obtained from a Global Positioning System (GPS) receiver on the device_

Comment: But <uses-feature> documentation states that android.hardware.location.gps (Only when target API level is 20 or lower.) so that means I should use android.hardware.location?

Comment: Based on this conversation, I don't think you even need the <uses-feature>. The main purpose of this (in my opinion) is to create a **filter** for devices that do not meet the requirement for your app. If you are setting the required field to **false**, you may as well remove it (unless you have other reasons). If you simply want to fetch the location of the device, ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>``` should be enough?

Comment: Yep I have same thoughts. Just asked this question because of the documentation note, which states that "Caution: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher and uses............."